How to Render Underline Text in Markdown Using Stream Chat SDK
I am currently working on a chat application using Stream SDK (https://getstream.io/). I have been running into continuous issues rendering underlined text in message bubbles. Stream seems to have no issue rendering other markdowns such as bold, italic, strikethrough, etc. but is continually unable to render underlined markdown.
Does anyone know any way to render underline within markdown as this issue has been driving me insane?
I am currently using version 8.36.0 (stream-chat); 11.21.0 (stream-chat-react)
I am also using React.js

You'll need to give us the bit of the code you're using that isn't working, and what's happening when you use it.

@Devin Markdown doesn't have underline syntax, so unsure what you're expecting.
